# Error loading my vs designer. Does not support code paring

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I receive the below error after loading a project in vs that was working the night before with no issue. Im confused about the error as I can access MedicalCentre.cs designer with no issues although it runs out of the same project/folder as the designers that result in the error. Im fairly new to this so forgive me if I explained the error poorly or miss out information. If anyone has any suggestions as to why I would get this error it would be greatly appreciated. 2 images are attched below

[Project frm folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuBDl.png)

[Error Loading designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chYCp.png)

Comment: Do you have a backup of the project?

Comment: A mistake im certain but no I haven't created a back up. However would I be able to directly transfer files to a new project?

Comment: Are you using source control?

Comment: I haven't used source control, though the option is in the file tab. Im not all to familiar with it

Comment: Then I guess you'll have  to sift through that cs file and see if you can figure out what the designer is unhappy with.

Comment: What's going on with that .MDF file?  Was it deleted?

Comment: Its just crazy to me as its a very primitive all It is is a windows form file with a few textboxes and labels. Theres really nothing there especially as its the same as the medicalcentre.cs file so confused as to why some work and others dont.

Comment: No? I can still coonect to the mdf file. I wouldnt have deleted the mdf as that is the crucial part of this project

Comment: Based on my research, please remove special characters from your folder such as '_'. Also please delete vs , bin and debug folder and rebuild it again.